# Setting Up Email on Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, email-server

I have server 2008 r2 and I'd like to setup email accounts.  What is the best way to do this?

I don't have the option of getting exchange server or anything else as I already have 2008 r2.  Based upon my basic google searches it doesn't appear as though r2 comes with pop or imap.  Is there a different way I'm supposed to be going about an email server?  SMTP is about all I can find and that doesn't allow for remote access or anything useful really.

This is for a side project on my own time, so its not mission critical, but 
I would like something that would allow people to login using thunderbird or outlook or whatever they use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We host mail for quite a few of our domains away from our main Exchange system.

I looked at a few email server programs and it came down to hMailServer or MailEnable, both of which are free and both of which should do what you want.

I chose hMail because it made some specific things I wanted to do simpler, but I doubt you'd have a problem with either.

Answer (score 0):

Years ago I had tried [Mercury](http://www.pmail.com/) (from the author of Pegaus Mail).

Answer (score 0):

I've used Mercury Mail for 10 years.

Answer (score 0):

The correct full name is Mercury/32, which includes POP, IMAP and SMTP.